# How to add a html button inside the top menu

Tags: magento2.4.5

[image: Top menu adding a button]

I am new in magento. How can I add an html button on that location?

Answer (score 0):

Do not know it has to be a button but you can add an hyperlink this way:

**in app\code\vendor\module\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="add_contact_us_menu" type="vendor\module\Plugin\TopMenu" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
```

**in app\code\vendor\module\Plugin\TopMenu.php**

```
<?php 
namespace vendor\module\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
class TopMenu
{
    protected $nodeFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }
    public function beforeGetHtml(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
        $outermostClass = '',
        $childrenWrapClass = '',
        $limit = 0
    ) 
    {

        
            $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
                [
                    'data' => [
                          'name' => __('Node title'),
                          'id' => 'cutom-page',
                          'url' =>  your url here,
                          'has_active' => false,
                          'is_active' => false 
                      ],
                     'idField' => 'id',
                     'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree(),

                  ]
        
            $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            'data' => [
                'name' => __('Contact Us'),
                'id' => 'cutom-page',
                'url' => 'http://magento244.local/what-is-new.html',
                      'has_active' => false,
                      'is_active' => false
                  ],
                 'idField' => 'id',
                 'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree(),
              ]);

        $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
```

Thank you @Joao71 This code is working but you missed );